# NodeJS - Confused about "Paths"

Tags: windows, node.js

When I installed `NodeJS` on my machine, I selected the "Add to PATH" option in the setup (Windows 8.1)

Later, when I used node to install .dotLess using the following command ... the path it installed to was...

> C:\Users\[Name]\AppRoaming etc etc...

It was an obscure path that was relative to my actual user account. I expected it to be more like ...

> C:\Program Files\node\....

So can someone explain to me how this works? I am really confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that .dotLess was installed only for your user account, while node.js was installed for all users. Typical installations will have an option for selecting one or the other.

Comment: Right, and I even used the `-g` flag, to make sure it was global. Isn't that what I am supposed to do?

Comment: Oh okay, so when installing a node package (via npm) you're not installing directly to the node installation folder. Node packages are meant to be entirely distinct from the node binary files. Installing with the `-g` flag means you'll have access to that node package anywhere, instead of just the folder where you ran `npm install [packagename]`. Does that make sense?

Comment: No.. not really. I'm still not understanding how I tell it to put the package in the node folder, and not the actual windows profile app data.

Comment: You don't :). Node packages aren't typically installed to `C:\Program Files\node`.

Comment: Hey, thank you a lot for the suggestion. While it wasn't a "direct" answer, it gave me enough actual information to start doing some research. The problem stemmed from the fact that I just had no earthly idea what the root of the issue was, and you gave me a grounding point to start research. I have solved this now.